# Why is the height of a div not at least the height of an image inside it?

Tags: html, css

Why is the height of the div not 400px like the image inside it?

```
<div>
    <img height ="400px" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png" />
</div>
<span>
    <img height ="100px" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png" />
</span>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZB3QD/28/**

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The (obsolete) height attribute takes either an integer or a percentage. It doesn't take a CSS length so should not have `px` as part of the value.

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted IMO. They have gone to the effort of providing a fiddle.

Comment: A link to example code on another site is a useful thing to provide, but a question must not depend on that other site in order to be understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full Height Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735760/full-height-image)

Answer (score 0):

Given only the code you have provided in the question: It does.

The code you link to is different. The div has an explicit height defined in the stylesheet, and that takes precedence.