# Full Height Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently building a website and I am running into some issues with side by side images and text:

```
<div class='banner' style='background-color: #efefef'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class='col-sm-8'>
        <div class='inner'>
          <div class='title'>Travel Bezaff</div>
          <div class='subtitle'>Like nothing you've ever experienced</div>
          <div class="paragraph" style="text-align: center">
            From the bustling streets of Casablanca to the dynamic capital city of Rabat to the labryinth like medina of the old city of Fez, prepare yourself for a journey into one of the most culturally diverse regions.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-sm-4'></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have two columns in a row, one for content and one for an image which would be located on the right hand side of the page. The content, as you can see, is already situated at the left side of the container.

I am just wondering how to make both columns of equal height. The image should completely fill the height for larger screen size, but it is certainly acceptable if the two columns stack over each other when collapsed to smaller screen sizes. How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I've provided a couple different ways that you could accomplish this (depending on which way you're actually looking for, since the screenshot above isn't super clear).

Here's a jsfiddle showing how this can be accomplished if you want your image to maintain the proper aspect ratio:

http://jsbin.com/xedijomuce/1/edit?css,output

And here's another jsfiddle showing how this can be accomplished if you want your image to always stretch to the full height of the monitor:

http://jsbin.com/nozagunoxo/1/edit?css,output

Basically, it uses the `flex` property to ensure that the two columns are always the same size. Then I've aligned them both vertically using `align-items: center` so the text will always be centered regardless of how tall the window gets.

```
.row-fluid {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I'll provide one final example shortly using `display: table-cell`, in case you're hoping to avoid `flex-box`.

Edit: as promised, here is a way to accomplish a similar effect using `display: table-cell`. This is the most supported solution, but requires a little more work. Good luck, let me know if you have any questions:

http://jsbin.com/mifupiwexi/1/edit?css,output

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to either implementation?

Comment: If you're looking for a (mostly) cross-browser solution, use the `display: table` version. The main drawbacks there are that you'll have to switch the styling more aggressively on mobile sizes, as the columns won't stack as `table-cells`. The `flex` solution has less support, but is much cleaner, intuitive and built to arrange columns - it might interact adversely with the Bootstrap grid system as well (because it handles all those items). The two flexbox solutions are just different ways of handling the image. Good luck!

Comment: My `inner` class has some padding. For some reason, your code does not work once I add some padding.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the Solution, If there is any problem, feel free to ask :-

I updated your code a little:-

```
<div class = 'banner' style = 'background-color: #efefef'>
            <div class = 'container-fluid'>

                <div class = "row-fluid">

                    <div class = 'col-sm-8' style="height:100px;">
                        <div class = 'inner'>
                            <div class = 'title'>Travel Bezaff</div>
                            <div class = 'subtitle'>Like nothing you've ever experienced</div>
                            <div class = "paragraph" style = "text-align: center">
                                From the bustling streets of Casablanca to the dynamic capital city of Rabat to the labryinth like medina of the old city of Fez, prepare yourself for a journey into one of the most culturally diverse regions.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = 'col-sm-4' style="height:100px;">
<img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" style="height:100%;">
</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

You just have to put the some particular height to both columns and set 100% height to image.
For example- I added a dummy image in the code, you can see that.

Comment: Keyword: **responsive** I'm not looking for something fixed. Surely, you don't think I'm that incompetent.

Comment: Sorry buddy, let me try some other solution. I will post my new answer soon